# How to make a serial queue with GCD

Tags: swift, parse-platform, grand-central-dispatch

I tried to make a serial queue for network operations with GCD like this:

```
let mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.mySerialQueue", dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0))


func myFunc() {
    dispatch_async(mySerialQueue) {

        do {
            // Get object from the database if it exists
            let query = PFQuery(className: aClass)
            query.whereKey(user, equalTo: currentUser)
            let result = try? query.getFirstObject()

            // Use existing object or create a new one
            let object = result ?? PFObject(className: aClass)
            object.setObject(currentUser, forKey: user)
            try object.save()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The code first looks for an existing object in the database.
If it finds one, it updates it. If it doesn't find one, it creates a new one. This is using the Parse SDK and only synchronous network functions (.getFirstObject, .save).

For some reason it seems that this is not executed serially, because a new object is sometimes written into the database, although one existed already that should have been updated only.

Am I missing something about the GCD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the [documentation on `dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class):**

> `relative_priority`: A negative offset from the maximum supported scheduler priority for the given quality-of-service class. **This value must be less than 0** and greater than MIN_QOS_CLASS_PRIORITY

**Therefore you should be passing in a value less than `0` for this.**

However, if you have no need for a priority, you can simply pass `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` into the `attr` argument when you create your queue. For example:

```
let mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.mySerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

Comment: So does that mean that offset 0 actually means no offset and thus the highest priority and that is equivalent to the main queue for UI modification?

Comment: @Manuel yes, you can assume that an offset of 0 is equivalent to the main queue (although the documentation never explicitly says this), so you should be using a value less than this.

Comment: @Manuel happy to help :)

Comment: @Manuel sorry, slight correction there, the offset is relative to the QOS class you're in, although you are using the highest QOS class, so you can assume that an offset of 0 would be equivalent to the main queue. If you're using a lower QOS class, then an offset of 0 doesn't really have any equivalent, but you still need to provide a value less than 0 (and above `MIN_QOS_CLASS_PRIORITY`).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Still I don't get why seriality and priority would be contradictory. Even if i passed a zero value (unless this was not allowed), the code executed on mySerialQueue should be FIFO, no? Also, strangely, when I open the link and search for the text I can't find it.

Comment: @Manuel you're right, seriality and priority are in no way contradictory. However, this is the only problem I could see with your code as it currently is, and therefore assumed (perhaps prematurely) that it must be interfering with the inner workings of the queue. I should have kept my previous comment, where I asked whether you had checked if this was a Parse issue by running this function on the main queue (and see if you're having the same problem). I'm not at all familiar with Parse though, so I'm afraid I can't offer you any help there.

Comment: thanks, I will replace the `dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class`with `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` and observe if it has anything to do with it. Digging into Parse issues is not really worth it anymore since it will be history soon. If it helps anyone: I implemented a workaround in Parse Cloud Code with `beforeSave` that would check if the object already exists and then updates it before allowing the client to write to the database.